How to change the starting point of planning under the plug-in using a topic or service
I need to be able to change the starting point of planning under the MotionPlanning plugin via topic or service(Moveit2). But I don't know how to do it.
Any guidance on resolving this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

The problem has been solved, please refer to: enter link description here

Welcome to Robotics MrVBian. Thanks for your answer but we prefer answers to be self contained where possible. Links tend to rot so answers which rely on a link can be rendered useless if the linked content disappears. If you add more context from the link, it is more likely that people will find your answer useful. See [answer] for more info.
